# Why does the % width and height for a shadow element in the shadow root of another customer element not work?

Tags: html, css, inheritance, custom-element

HTML:

```
<options-container>
  <options-panel panel-type=“login”></options-panel>
</options-container>
```

Parent custom element styles:

```
options-container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  height: calc(100vh - 52px);
  height: calc(100vh - (45px + 0.3vw));
  min-height: max(calc(56.25vw - 52px), calc(100vh - 52px));
  min-height: max(calc(56.25vw - (45px + 0.3vw)), calc(100vh - (45px + 0.3vw)));
  position: fixed;
  top: 52px;
  top: calc(45px + 0.3vw);
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: calc(300px + 3vw);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
  will-change: width;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Child element (in the shadow root of the above element) styles:

```
:host {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100vh;
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 10vw;
  background-color: var(--white, white);
  border: 2px solid var(--light-gray, lightgray);
  border: 0.2vw solid var(--light-gray, lightgray);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: calc(8px + 0.3vw);
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px var(--shadow, black);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px calc(8px + 0.3vw) 0px var(--shadow, black);
  pointer-events: auto;
  animation: fly-down 1.5s ease-out;
  animation-play-state: running;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out 0.5s;
  -o-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out 0.5s;
  transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out 0.5s;
  will-change: max-height;
}
```

Parent Element Box Model

[image: Parent Element Box Model]

Child Element Box Model

[image: Child Element Box Model]

Having real trouble trying to explain this behaviour, and more trouble trying to get the child element to become visible. I may be missing something really small, I don't know. But any guidance and/or explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please add html code.

Comment: @RayeesAC added

Comment: Why `inline-flex`? And also, why have you repeated the flexbox inside of the child? Is there another layer lower than this in the tree? And also do you have to use the weird `:host` thing from Angular? So many weird things in your code...

Comment: Height and width will have no effect on `inline` style display elements. They are trying to adjust to contents within. In general that css is looking pretty confusing, with fixed positioning, height, width, flex, and transitions together. I would break those up into separate containers.

Comment: @serraosays :host is not “from” Angular, it is being used since these are inline styles for a custom element, and is the only viable way to style a custom element from its shadow root. There are layers lower than this, but since the height and width properties are present in this CSS snippet, there shouldn’t be any reason (at least not one I can see) why they should not be adhered to

Comment: @hyperdrive I've tried removing "inline-" from "inline-flex" to no avail. I genuinely don't think that's the issue. This exact stylesheet was working perfectly before I made them into custom elements, so I really do believe it's an inheritance issue that I'm missing

Comment: Make it working code, either in an SO snippet (button on the editor bar) Or better yet a JSFiddle or CodePen so it is easier for us to tinker with. Strip down everything that has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Tried, but hit an issue since there is a limitation to one file. (Not ideal, I know) but could you try and view https://www.trendineer.com and mess about with DevTools, or, if you know how to put all of it into a fiddle-equivalent, be able to make one better than me?

Comment: Can't help; trying to understand the basics of your whole site would take 10+ minutes. You have to slim down your problem to the minimum code base where the error occurs. Then people can/will help. That is how we all debug: strip away everything that doesn't apply.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I've created a page dedicated to this - please feel free to take a look. I'd really appreciate any help and knowledge you can offer! https://www.trendineer.com/options-panel.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer found!

Embarrassing, rookie error, I had attached a shadow root to the `<options-container>` element, which is why the child elements were not being rendered. Nothing to do with the CSS at all.

Note to self and others in a similar situation: Check the shadow root.

Doing

<strike>this.shadowroot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});</strike>

was the answer.